# Scaling three divs with background image inside a container with another background image issue

Tags: html, css

I am currently dealing with an issue that took me all day. I have a container with a background image that has 3 divs with a background image(img size:185x2035) each . I am trying to make it fluid but the issue is that when I resize the screen , the 3 divs increase in height and decrease in width.
I used procentual width for the container and for the 3 divs I used fixed width and height.
Is there a fix for this ? maybe a js script or something ? it's really annyoing me.
I'll also post the code,thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="slot-machine">
        <div class="scale-please">


            <div class="slot-strip"></div>
            <div class="slot-strip"></div>
            <div class="slot-strip"></div>


        </div>
      </div>


    </body>

    </html>


    /*   --- My styling --- */
    * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      border:0 none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,body {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }

    body {
      background:url("bg.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      width:100%;
      padding:200px 0;
    }

    .slot-machine {
      background:url("slot-machine.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
      margin:auto;
      width:90%;
      height: 240px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;

    }

    .scale-please {
      width:400px;
      height:200px;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top:50px;

    }

    .slot-strip {
      background:url("slot-strip.png");
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      background-size: cover;
      float:left;
      width:90px;
      height:90px;
      z-index: 4;
      padding-top:70px;
      border:1px solid red;

    }

    .slot-strip:nth-child(2) {
      margin-left:25px;
      margin-right: 25px;
    }






    @media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
      .slot-machine {
        width:98%;
        background-size: contain;

      }

      .scale-please {
        width:42%;
      }

      .slot-strip {
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
      }
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 780px)  {
      .scale-please {


      }


    }
```

Also I would like to keep the images as background because I can use background position to make a spin animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

> The flex-wrap CSS property sets whether flex items are forced onto one
>   line or can wrap onto multiple lines. If wrapping is allowed, it sets
>   the direction that lines are stacked.

To be short: try adding `flex-wrap:wrap;` to `.scale-please`

Without it, the flex children are just trying to fit in one line and stretch.
You'll probably have some fixes to make, but mostly it should solve your problem.

(example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMWaqa , you should try making one of these when asking that kind of question, or one of these: https://jsfiddle.net/ , its way easier for us to help you)

Comment: I want to keep them on the same line , flex wrap will set them like a column when I resize the browser.

Comment: @clauu Yes, and that's pure logic: at a certain breakpoint you set the container to 42% width and the children to 70px.
When the container gets to 200px, it can't fit 3 elements with 70px, because we get 210px.
The solution is to simply reduce the children element's width, or to increase the container width to something bigger than 42% and that will always be at least 210px wide.